# Maven - multi module application - problem with clean install

Tags: spring, maven, multi-module

I have a multi modular application,
I need to import some classes from the parent module (they are similar for all modules)
So as intellij prompts, I made a dependency to the parent module 
(this is my first multi module app)

The problem is that when I do

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I have a build failure.
It seems that maven is seeking my parent project from the dependency online, where obviously it doesn't exist, and it should look locally... I think

Actually the applications can be build, and run, but I cannot make a package, I cannot install it...

How can I resolve it?
here is some code:

pom.xml for parent:

```
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>eu.mrndesign.matned</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>../credit</module>
    <module>../client</module>
    <module>../product</module>
</modules>

<name>parent</name>
<description>Description</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
        ...
</dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

One of the children pom (they are 3 and they look almost the same):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.mrndesign.matned</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<parent>
    <groupId>eu.mrndesign.matned</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>product</artifactId>
<name>product</name>
<description>Product module for create credit application</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

And here is the message when clean install:

```
[INFO] ---------------------< eu.mrndesign.matned:credit >---------------------
[INFO] Building credit 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [2/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.857 s]
[INFO] credit ............................................. FAILURE [  0.133 s]
[INFO] client ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] product ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.237 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-09T03:53:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project credit: Could not resolve dependencies for project eu.mrndesign.matned:credit:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find eu.mrndesign.matned:parent:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repo.spring.io/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: When you have multi-module project the parent pom would have `packaging` of type `pom`. Which means it does not generate any artifacts and hence you cannot use it as dependency. There are ways around it by using plugins etc but a general maven way is to not have any code in parent project, it should be used to define modules, dependency-management, common dependencies and plugin configuration, etc.

Comment: Thanks Setu, You are right. I have done another module , moved the classes there. Now  it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent cannot contain code and therefore cannot be used as a dependency.

Put your classes into a module and use that module as dependency in other modules.

Comment: Thanks  lot, that's what I wanted to hear :) Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove parent dependency declaration from the child module. The parent markup is already enough to specify that module is part of the parent module

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>eu.mrndesign.matned</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>product</artifactId>
<name>product</name>
<description>Product module for create credit application</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: but without it I cannot use classes from parent, isn't it?

Comment: if you want to use other modules you can directly add those modules into the dependencies. If you want to use all the classes available, then you didn't need to break it into multiple modules.